# Javascript: filter date data then reduce method does not work

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, helper

I am trying making basic Todo list. I have created basic React todo list and save it to my database. I set `dueDatetime` query where it sets the time. I made query  like this:

```
 {
      “overdue”: [],
       “today”: [],
       “tomorrow”: [],
       rest of the upcoming dates
    }
```

I have made one helper function where it will get the data. Display the length of the tasks. My `Overdue`, `today` and `tomorrow` task display as expected but my rest of the upcoming tasks length does work properly. The result expected like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39cQm.png). But I am getting this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GRbF.png). I filter the rest of the date data then used reduce method and try to get same dates tasks length but my logic does not work. I don't what I am making mistake. I think My reduce function logic does not work. I share my code in [CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-task-vmg64?file=/src/App.js)

**My Helper function**

```
export const groupByDates = (data) => {
  const oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
  let today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setSeconds(0);
  today.setMilliseconds(0);
  today = today.getTime();
  const overdue = data.filter(
    (task) => new Date(task).getTime() < today
  );
  const todayTask = data.filter((task) => {
    const due = new Date(task).getTime();
    return due >= today && due < today + oneDay;
  });
  const tomorrow = data.filter((task) => {
    const due = new Date(task).getTime();
    return due >= today + oneDay && due < today + oneDay * 2;
  });
  const rest = data.filter( // this logic does not work 
    (task) => new Date(task).getTime() >= today + oneDay * 2
  ).reduce((groups, d) => {
    const key = d?.toString().slice(0, 15);
    console.log(key);

    if (!groups[key]) {
      groups[key] = [];
    }
    groups[key].push(d);
    return groups;
  }, {});

  return { overdue, today: todayTask, tomorrow, rest: Object.keys(rest) };
};
```

**This is my frontend code.`****

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import date from "./Date.json";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const signledate = date?.data?.map((i) => {
    return new Date(i.dueDatetime);
  });
  // console.log(signledate);

  const datadate = date?.data?.slice(0, 1)?.map((i) => {
    return i.dueDatetime;
  });
  console.log(signledate);
  console.log(new Date());
  return (
    <Container>
      <Card>
        <Text>You have 10 overdue</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Today you have 6 tasks</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Tomorrow you have 20 tasks</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Jan 23 5 task </Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Jan 24 2 task </Text>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

const Card = styled.div`
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
`;

const Text = styled.text`
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px;
`;
```

**This is my dymmydata in json**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-21T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-03-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-23T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-25T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-04-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-04-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-04-26T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-05-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-05-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-05-24T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-02-07T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-06-17T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-21T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-07-05T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-07-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-07-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-07-19T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-08-02T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-08-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-08-16T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-08-30T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-09-13T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-09-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-09-16T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-23T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-21T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-10-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-10-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-10-25T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-11-08T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-11-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-11-22T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-12-06T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-12-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-12-16T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2019-12-20T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-03T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-15T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-17T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-01-31T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-02-14T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-02-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-02-17T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-22T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-03-13T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-03-14T22:28:14Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-03-15T16:30:11.007867Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2020-03-16T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-27T13:37:56.587949Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "weeks",
        "interval": 2,
        "day": null,
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    },
    {
      "dueDatetime": "2021-01-23T14:30:22.149836Z",
      "repeatInformation": {
        "type": "months",
        "interval": 1,
        "day": "any weekday",
        "annualStart": null,
        "annualEnd": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code:

Date.js

```
export const groupByDates = (data) => {
  const oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
  let today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setSeconds(0);
  today.setMilliseconds(0);
  today = today.getTime();
  const overdue = data.filter((task) => new Date(task).getTime() < today);
  const todayTask = data.filter((task) => {
    const due = new Date(task).getTime();
    return due >= today && due < today + oneDay;
  });
  const tomorrow = data.filter((task) => {
    const due = new Date(task).getTime();
    return due >= today + oneDay && due < today + oneDay * 2;
  });
  const rest = data
    .filter((task) => new Date(task).getTime() >= today + oneDay * 2)
    .reduce((groups, d) => {
      const key = d?.toString().slice(0, 15);
      console.log(key);

      if (!groups[key]) {
        groups[key] = [];
      }
      groups[key].push(d);
      return groups;
    }, {});

  return { overdue, today: todayTask, tomorrow, rest: rest };
};
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";

import date from "./date.json";
import { groupByDates } from "./Date";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const dummyData = date?.data?.map((i) => i.dueDatetime);
  const groupedDate = groupByDates(dummyData);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Card>
        <Text>You have {groupedDate.overdue.length} overdue</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Today you have {groupedDate.today.length} tasks</Text>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <Text>Tomorrow you have {groupedDate.tomorrow.length} tasks</Text>
      </Card>
      {Object.keys(groupedDate.rest).map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <Card key={index}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
            <Text>{groupedDate?.rest[item].length}</Text>
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how you fixed it. Code–only answers are pretty useless for others who might have the same issue.